# How to convert Parse ObjectId (String) to long?

Tags: java, parse-platform

Every object in Parse.com has your own ObjectId, that is a string with 10 char and apparently it is created by this regex: `[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}`.

Example of ObjectId in Parse:

- X12wEq4sFf
- Weg243d21s
- zwg34GdsWE

I would like to convert this String to Long, because it will save memory and improve searching. (10 chars using UTF-8 has 40 bytes, and 1 long has 8 bytes)

If we calculate the combinations, we can find:

- **String ObjectId:** 62^10 = 839299365868340224 different values;
- **long:** is 2^64 = 18446744073709551616 different values.

So, we can convert these values without losing information. There is a simple way to do it safely? Please, consider any kind of encoding for Chars (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc);

EDIT: I am just thinking in a hard way to solved it. I am asking if there is an easy way.

Comment: @Paulo-Long data type is a 64-bit/8-byte signed two's complement integer. And, its maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive)(2^63 -1)

Comment: @shekharsuman You are only considering positive values. But if you consider negative values, we have 2^64

Comment: @Paulo-I talked about maximum value of long in Java 7, from Java 8, you can consider unsigned long upto 2^64-1. And, sorry, I misunderstood that you were talking about different possible values. And, I was thinking about max. possible value. You are correct here.

Comment: Am I missing the obvious here? 62 possible characters can be trivially encoded into 6 bits. And 6*10 bits can be trivially fit into a `long`.

Comment: @biziclop 62 possible char powered by 10, because we have 10 chars.

Comment: @Paulo are the letter case sensitive?

Comment: @Asaph Yes. The regex to create it is `[0-9a-zA-Z]{10}`

Comment: @Paulo That looks different than the regex in your question, which includes the dash character too (and is malformed because of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your character set is a subset of the commonly-used Base64 encoding, so you could just use that. Java has the [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class, no need to roll your own codec for this.
2. Are you sure this is actually valuable? *"because it will save memory and improve searching"* seems like an untested assertion; saving a few bytes on the IDs may very well be offset by the added cost of encoding and decoding every time you want to use something.

EDIT: Also, why are you using UTF-8 strings for guaranteed-ascii data? If you represent 10 char IDs as a `byte[10]`, that's just 10 bytes instead of 40 (i.e. *much* closer to the 8 for a `long`). And you don't need to do any fancy conversions.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said, but how about some code?

Comment: I fully agree with the second point, not convinced about the usefulness of base64 encoding for this task. (if, as you say, it's a task worth doing at all, which is questionable.)

Comment: @Paulo You can store it as byte[10] too, as all your characters are within the standard ASCII range.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't think code is required for "how do I use this built-in library"...

Comment: @biziclop thanks for the correction, switched answer to `byte`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution using 6 bits to store a single character.

```
public class Converter {

    private static final String CHARS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 

    private static int convertChar(char c) {
        int ret = CHARS.indexOf( c );
        if (ret == -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Invalid character encountered: "+c);
        return ret;
    }

    public static long convert(String s) {
        if (s.length() != 10)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "String length must be 10, was "+s.length() );
        long ret = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            ret = (ret << 6) + convertChar( s.charAt( i ));
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I'll leave the conversion from `long` to `String` for you to implement, it's basically the same in reverse.

P.s.: If you really want to save space, don't use `Long`, it adds nothing compared to the primitive `long` except overhead.

P.s 2: Also note that you aren't really saving much with this conversion: storing the ASCII characters can be done in 10 bytes, while a `long` takes up 4. What you save here is mostly the overhead you'd get if you stored those 10 bytes in a byte array.